# Using pre_get_posts to filter out posts, pagination problem

Tags: pagination, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to figure out how to fix my pagination problem while filtering out posts on the fly.

I have a dropdown box just above the category archive that allows a user to sort or filter out posts based on custom fields.

The posts, filter just fine on the first page. My problem shows up the minute I filter posts from within 2'nd or deeper page because filtering them out also reduces the number of existing pages. This returns a 404 error for me.

I was wondering how to modify this to also **check if the page exists**, if not... return to first page.

`$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Updated the code as requested:

```
// ADD SORT QUERY VAR
add_action( 'init', 'sort_rewrite_rules' );
function sort_rewrite_rules() {
    // SORT QUERY VAR
    add_rewrite_tag( '%sort%', '([^/]+)' );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts',11 );
function filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // DON'T AFFECT WP-ADMIN SCREENS
    if ( is_admin() )
        return;
// SORT ADS FROM THE MAIN QUERY
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$sort = get_query_var( 'sort' );
if ( $query->is_main_query() && $sort ) {


    //EXCLUDE EXPIRED POSTS
    if ( 'expired' == $sort ) {
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $metaquery = array(
                        array(
                             'key' => 'expire_date',
                             'value' => $today,
                             'type' => 'DATETIME',
                             'compare' => '>'
                    )
            );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $metaquery );
        $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
    }

}
}


<div id="sort">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <select name="sort" id="sort-dropdown">

<option value="expired" <?php selected( get_query_var( 'sort' ), 'expired' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Exclude Expired Posts', 'txt' ); ?></option>

   </select>
        <button type="submit" id="sort-submit">Sort</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably return the user to the first page of results following a search in all scenarios, to be consistent.

If you did need to check though you can use the following:

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

So if there's only 2 pages and you're on page 3 then you need to redirect to the start.

Comment: Just had a look at this and while it looked valid, I can't seem to return the value for max_num_pages, its always 0.
Current page value is returned properly.

Comment: You'll only have this information to you after the query has been performed. Therefore you'll probably have to do all of this on template_redirect

Comment: Using template_redirect does pass the max_num_pages value but then I also need to redirect the page itself because the URL is stuck on the same page number. I also need to preserve the query string after redirect.